# How many lattices require exactly 3 elements to generate them?

Tags: co.combinatorics

This question by Moshe Newman:

How many different lattices are there on n points, that require
exactly 3 elements to generate them? This sequence seems to start
0,0,1,0,4,3 (for n = 1 to 6) and seems not be be in the OEIS.

Comment: It is a little confusing to say "on $n$ points" when what you mean is $n$-element lattices up to isomorphism.

Comment: I can only guess what the question is. Do you mean to classify the pairs $(H, Z^n)$ consisting of a subgroup $H$ of standard $Z^n$ \st $Z^n/H$ is exactly three-generated (as an abelian group), up to GL($n, Z$) acting on $Z^n$? That is, the number of equivalence classes ... [Here $Z$ means the integers; I was too lazy to use bold $Z$, because MO doesn't allow macros to be defined.]

Comment: @DavidHandelman this is about partially ordered sets that have meets and joins

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Ahh, that explains it. I am currently thinking about sublattices of $R^n$ (meaning discrete subgroups), hence my confusion. Whenever *lattice* is mentioned, it should be disambiguated.

Comment: Languages like French are more sensible: *reseau* vs. *treillis*.